# Writing UTF-8 in file

Tags: python, unicode, error-handling, utf-8

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open("C:\\Users\suasnomy\Desktop\python files\checkers.txt", 'r','utf-8')
fo = codecs.open('writehere.txt','a','utf-8')
for line in f:
    l = line.split(' ')
    fo.write(l[0]+'\n')
```

This code reads the first word of the file checkers and write in the writehere.
But the problem is it shows some rectangle infront of the word printed here that is this हेलोप्रिय.
It must change the line after हेलो and then should print प्रिय in next line but it joins both.
[image: it shows the file from where we read and how it is written in writehere file.]

Characters are not printed in cmd and thats ok. But in file it leaves 2 lines if i append in existing file..
Please help to fix this code..

Comment: This may be because your language encoding doesn't support the `/n` character, and UTF-8 might read that as an empty rectangle. Instead, do an actual line break and see if that works

Comment: Apply [`utf_8_sig` encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.utf_8_sig) in `f = codecs.open(infile,'r','utf_8_sig')`.

Comment: Just don't use `codecs.open`.  Use `open` on Python 3 or `io.open` in Python 2 (or Python 3...it's a backport and compatibility layer with Python 3's `open`).  `codecs.open` has issues (it always opens files in binary mode and doesn't do newline translation on Windows, for example) and is no longer needed.  `utf-8-sig` is a good idea for opening files for reading files (it will remove a sig if present), and is also a good idea for writing files on Windows.  Windows text files without the UTF-8 BOM signature are assumed to be in a localized ANSI encoding by most Windows editors.